# How can I get terms (post_tag) of custom taxonomy item? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I created custom post type 'photo' and custom taxonomy 'catphoto'.

The type 'photo' supports 'catphoto' and 'post_tag' as taxonomies.

Now I should make one filter for a client.

I need to show on **taxonomy-catphoto.php** page all `post_tags`, which belong to the current 'catphoto' item.

For example, I have a post of custom post type 'photo'. The name of this post is 'Plane'. This post belongs to '*1961-1981*' catphoto item. Also it has post tags like '*space*', '*planes*', '*stars*', '*war*'.

Also, for example, I have a post of 'photo' which name is 'Soldier'. It belongs to '*1941-1961*' catphoto item and has '*WW2*', '*USA*', '*USSR*' like post tags.

And now when I select 1941-1961 catphoto item I should get a list with:
*WW2*
*USA*
*USSR*

I try like this:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1,8) == 'catphoto'){
    $cur_terms = get_terms('post_tag');
    if ($cur_terms) {
        foreach( $cur_terms as $cur_term ){
            echo $cur_term->name.'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Now I get all post tags of all catphoto items. How can I fix to restrict for definite catphoto item. For example, '*1941-1961*' ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this via $_GET query. So easy...
For beginning, I had decided to create own taxonomy type (like post_tags). Its name is 'mark'.

and after that the snippet is:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1,8) == 'catphoto'){
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 

    $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'photo', 'catphoto' => $term->name));

    echo '<ul>';

    $uniqueTerms = array();
    $uniqueSlugs = array();
    $uniquePar = $term->slug;

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        $query->the_post();
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'mark', array("fields" => "all"));

        foreach ($terms as $term1)
        {
            if(!in_array($term1->name, $uniqueTerms)) {
               $uniqueTerms[] = $term1->name;
               $uniqueSlugs[] = $term1->slug; 
            }
        }   
    } 

    for ($var = 0; $var < count($uniqueTerms); $var++)
        echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/catphoto/' ) ).$uniquePar.'/?mark='.$uniqueSlugs[$var].'">'.$uniqueTerms[$var].'</a></li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

So ugly code here and there but it works.

and now in **taxonomy-catphoto.php** I fill in:

```
$mark = $_GET['mark'];
```

and after that a little change inside WP_Query query

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'photo', 'posts_per_page'=>56, 'paged'=> $paged, 'catphoto' => $term->name, 'mark' =>$mark) );
```

Best regards, Igor